# Is there a way to get background updates from the Google Fit API?

Tags: android, service, background, google-fit

What I'd like is to receive a callback when step count surpasses a certain threshold.

I imagine the solution is to create a service that calls the History API at fixed intervals.

Comment: Hi skoush!
I'm also looking for a same solution - have you found anything yet?

Comment: Have you found anything?